# EF 6.4.4 Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'SaleDetail_Ledger_Target' of the relationship 'BLL.SaleDetail_Ledger' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.4

I am trying to update an entity named SaleLedger with some relationships in it. But while calling `Context.SaveChanges()` it throws an exception

I am using EF 6.4.4 and SQL Server database

My Entity is

```
public class SaleLedger
  {  
      [DisplayName("Inv. Code")]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Customer")]
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Sale Category Id")]
      public int? CatId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Customer Id")]
      public int? CustId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Salesman Id")]
      public int? SalesManId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("SalesMan Name")]
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? SalesManName { get; set; }
      public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Disc %")]
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(5,2)]
      public decimal DiscPerc { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Disc")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal DiscVal { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Flat Disc")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal FlatDisc { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("+")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal MiscCharges { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("GST %")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(5,2)]
      public decimal SalesTaxPerc { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("GST")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal SalesTaxVal { get; set; }
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? Posted { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Posting Date")]
      public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
      [StringLength(200)]
      public string? Remarks { get; set; }
      public DateTime? OriginalDate { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Posted By User Id")]
      public short? PostedByUserId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Posted By")]
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? PostedByName { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Posted By Machine Id")]
      public short? PostedByMachineId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Posted By Machine")]
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? PostedByMachineName { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Printed")]
      public int RePrintingCounter { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Received Cash")]
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal? CashReceived { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Print Warranty")]
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? PrintWaranty { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Print Batch")]
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? PrintBatch { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Inv. Size")]
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? InvoiceSize { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Inv. Total")]
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal? InvTotal { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Modif. Count")]
      public int? ModifyCounter { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Paid Status")]
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? PaidStatus { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Billing Date")]
      public DateTime? BillingDate { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("UnReceived Balance")]
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal? UnReceivedBalance { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Total Of Sale Returns")]
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal? TotalOfSaleReturns { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Outstanding")]
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal? OutStandingAmt { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Print Balance")]
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? PrintBalance { get; set; }
      [Column(TypeName ="decimal")]  [DecimalPrecision(18,2)]
      public decimal? Balance { get; set; }
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? Deleted { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("AccountCode")]
      public string? AccountCode { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Sale Order Id")]
      public int? SaleOrderId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Due Date")]
      public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
      [StringLength(100)]
      [DisplayName("Sale Category")]
      public string? SaleCategoryName { get; set; }
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? PrintExpiry { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("CatId")]
      [InverseProperty("Ledgers")]
      public virtual SaleCategory? Category { get; set; }
      [InverseProperty("Ledger")]
      public virtual List<SaleDetail>? Details { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Type Id")]
      public short? TypeId { get; set; }
      [InverseProperty("Ledgers")]
      [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
      public virtual SaleType? Type { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("CustId")]
      [InverseProperty("SaleLedgers")]
      public virtual Customer? Customer { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("SalesManId")]
      [InverseProperty("SaleLedgers")]
      public virtual Salesman? SalesMan { get; set; }
      [NotMapped]
      [DisplayName("No.")]
      public int SrNo { get; set; }
      [StringLength(100)]
      public string? Name { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Saved By Id")]
      public short? SavedById { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Saved By Machine Id")]
      public short? SavedByMachineId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Saved Date")]
      public DateTime? SavedDate { get; set; }
      [StringLength(100)]
      [DisplayName("Saved By")]
      public string? SavedByName { get; set; }
      [StringLength(100)]
      [DisplayName("Saved By Machine")]
      public string? SavedByMachineName { get; set; }
      [StringLength(1)]
      public string? Active { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("SavedById")]
      public virtual User? SavedByUser { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("SavedByMachineId")]
      public virtual Machine? SavedByMachine { get; set; }
  }
```

SaleDetail Entity is

```
public class SaleDetail
 {
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Sale Item Id")]
     public int? SItemId { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Sale Item Name")]
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string? SItemName { get; set; }
     [StringLength(200)]
     public string? Batch { get; set; }
     public DateTime? Expiry { get; set; }
     public int? Qty { get; set; }
     public int? Packs { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Pack Units")]
     public int? PackUnits { get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     [DisplayName("Pcs Sale Amount")]
     public decimal? PcsSaleAmount { get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? Rate { get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(5, 2)]
     [DisplayName("Disc %")]
     public decimal? DiscPerc { get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(5, 2)]
     [DisplayName("Sales Tax")]
     public decimal? SalesTax { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Row Id")]
     public int? RowID { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Due Qty")]
     public int? DueQty { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Satisfied Date")]
     public DateTime? SatisfiedDate { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Pack Sale Amount")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? PackSaleAmount { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Unit Sales Tax")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? UnitSalesTax { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("GST %")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(5, 2)]
     public decimal? GSTPerc { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Pack Bonus Qty")]
     public int? PackBonusQty { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Pcs Bonus Qty")]
     public int? PcsBonusQty { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Pur Unit Rate")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? PurUnitRate { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("MRP Unit Rate")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? MRPUnitRate { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Gross Amount")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? GrossAmount { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Add %")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(5, 2)]
     public decimal? AddPerc { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Add Value")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? AddVal { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Disc Value")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? DiscVal { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Net Amount")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? NetAmount { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("GST Value")]
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     public decimal? GSTVal { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Sale Inv Id")]
     public int? SaleInvId { get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     [DisplayName("Flat Disc.")]
     public decimal? FlatDisc { get; set; }
     [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
     [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
     [DisplayName("Total Disc")]
     public decimal? TotalDiscVal { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Initial Packs Stock")]
     public int? InitialPackStock { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Initial Pcs Stock")]
     public int? InitialPcsStock { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Balance Packs Stock")]
     public int? BalancePackStock { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Balance Pcs Stock")]
     public int? BalancePcsStock { get; set; }
     [InverseProperty("Details")]
     [ForeignKey("SaleInvId")]
     public virtual SaleLedger? Ledger { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("SItemId")]
     public virtual Item? SItem { get; set; }
 }
```

Actually I am trying to update an entity named SaleLedger with some relationships in it.

While calling `Context.SaveChanges()` in update

It throws an exception saying.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'SaleDetail_Ledger_Target' of the relationship 'BLL.SaleDetail_Ledger' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.VerifyNavigationPropertyForAdd(IEntityWrapper wrapper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.AddRelationshipDetectedByGraph(Dictionary`2 relationships, Object relatedObject, RelatedEnd relatedEndFrom, Boolean verifyForAdd)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInRelationshipsOfSingleEntity()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInNavigationProperties(IList`1 entries)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at DAL.SaleLedgerDAL.SaveSaleLedger(SaleLedger cust) in E:\Aamir\Ehsan\MedTradeSolutionWinforms\DAL\SaleLedgerDAL.cs:line 290
   at DesktopUI.FrmSaleInvoice.SaveInvoice() in E:\Aamir\Ehsan\MedTradeSolutionWinforms\DesktopUI\FrmSaleInvoice.cs:line 713
   at DesktopUI.FrmSaleInvoice.BtnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Aamir\Ehsan\MedTradeSolutionWinforms\DesktopUI\FrmSaleInvoice.cs:line 1907
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at DesktopUI.Program.Main() in E:\Aamir\Ehsan\MedTradeSolutionWinforms\DesktopUI\Program.cs:line 19
```

Comment: You have a circular reference in SaleLedger on Details: public virtual List<SaleDetail>? Details { get; set; } and in  SaleDetail:  public virtual SaleLedger? Ledger { get; set; }

Comment: I am trying to define a one to many relationship actually.
How do i do it correctly then?